# How can I translate all the contents of a div from Spanish into English in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `div` that has as its content a dynamic text that it receives through a web service. I would like this content to be translated from Spanish (original language) - into English. How can I do it? I have seen some libraries that translate words, but this happens, also adding the translation, in my case they are small dynamic texts.

```
<div>
 esto es un texto dinámico
</div
```

the result should be

```
<div>
 this is a dynamic text
</div
```

this is my code:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController as $ctrl">
 <div>
    esto es un texto dinámico
 </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nm2h9d5o/

Comment: show us your code, the angular controller and the template

Comment: https://angular-translate.github.io

Comment: @Zooly I must know the translation of the text. in my case the texts are dynamic so it will not work

Comment: @messerbill look https://jsfiddle.net/nm2h9d5o/

Comment: updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nm2h9d5o/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is solved using `Interpolation` in Angular. You should get familiar with it. http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-compile-parse-interpolate/

controller side:

```
//...
$scope.myContent = getMyContent()
```

template side:

```
<div>{{myContent}}</div>
```

The `getMyContent()` method should return the text in your wanted language.

Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nm2h9d5o/2/

Comment: the example.. not works..

Comment: _"Don't re-invent a wheel"_. There is an official module for **Internationalization** - [i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n). The module also support filters (dates/currency/etc.)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Can you give me an example that fits my need please?

Comment: @yavg in your case, you either need to translate it manually and just keep in placeholders that you change with a selected language (like a switch case / if statements), OR you need to get a 3rd party API for dynamic translations (which usually are not free)

Comment: `just keep in placeholders` which would be done the way i explanied ;)

Comment: @yavg this is the standard way, thus your code is wrong somewhere else

Comment: @yavg it works....updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nm2h9d5o/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at one of the most common used `AngularJS` translate libraries. (also mentioned in the comments of your question).

Take a look at: [Angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/).

In this case you could use the `| translate` definition within the view. Within the `app.js` configuration you're able to set your languages and an switch for the languages if you'd like to. In this way you would be able to dynamicly switch / change languages if you want to.

A simple build example down below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login_view.html',
            title: 'login'
        })
   $translateProvider
        .translations('en', {
            'Opslaan': 'Save',
   })
        .translations('nl', {
            'Opslaan': 'Opslaan',
   });
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en'); // default language
   });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="my-app">
      <div class="test">
      <p> {{'Opslaan' | translate }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The :`$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');` Sets the default language to english. You're able to create as many language libraries as you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the problem is that he wants to translate them automatically, so you can't store them in `$translateProvider`